Remove azure fileshare with RSV backup enabled via terraform gives error of share or snapshots may have active leases
I have two recovery service vaults in two different regions, south east asia and west europe.
But I only get this error message when using terraform to destroy the azure fileshare that has snapshot inside for SEA only. I did the same testing for fileshare in west europe, no error at all.
deleting File Share "seashare" (Account "Account \"myseafileshare\" (IsEdgeZone false / ZoneName \"\" / Subdomain Type \"file\" / DomainSuffix \"core.windows.net\")"): executing request: unexpected status 409 (409 Unable to delete share because one or more share snapshots have active leases. Release the share snapshot leases or delete the share with the include-leased parameter for x-ms-delete-snapshots.) with DeleteShareWhenSnapshotLeased: Unable to delete share because one or more share snapshots have active leases. Release the share snapshot leases or delete the share with the include-leased parameter for x-ms-delete-snapshots.

Both using the same azurerm provider 3.116.0 and I created both RSV using same terraform configuration except location. Both RSV have the soft delete enabled on these properties : Enable soft delete for cloud workloads, Enable soft delete and security settings for hybrid workloads.
I am able to terraform destroy the seashare after I turn off the Enable soft delete for cloud workloads, Enable soft delete and security settings for hybrid workloads and manually delete the snapshot for the seashare.
I checked the lease on the file as well. REST file lease:  State -> Available , Lock -> Unlocked
Any idea on why the behaviour could be different when they are having same RSV setting / azure fileshare setting except location?

check if the snapshot was in locked or release state @cookick


RSV backup enabled via terraform gives error of share or snapshots may have active leases

Since both backups are in different locations there are active leases on one or more snapshots which results in causing the error. Check if there are any snapshots associated with the file share that might be locked by the leases.

Make sure you're using the same version as you provisioned using while creating the resource as because of updating version you might get the compatability issues.
Run the command
 az storage share-rm list --storage-account "storageaccountname" --include-deleted --include-snapshot  

once the conformation done, please check with lease state for the snapshots.
and run the commands
terraform destory

Deployment:

refer:
Overview of Azure Files share snapshots | Microsoft Learn
az storage share | Microsoft Learn

Yes I have tried to use az storage share show and get this
"lease": {
"duration": null,
"state": "available",
"status": "unlocked"
}.
Another issue I noticed is that deleting azurerm_backup_container_storage_account cause the storage acc in Backup Infrastucture shows as "Soft Deleted" and I have to disable the soft delete of the RSV, then undelete the recovery point, and delete the backup successfully (which delete the snapshot). Then I can terraform destroy successfully. It was able to delete all in one run for WEU resources, but not for SEA.

try temporarily disable soft delete on the Recovery Services Vault (RSV) to avoid the "soft deleted" status when removing resources this task should be run before terraform destroy command @cookick

But the same soft delete feature is enabled in WEU RSV and can delete files hare/ backup without any issue. So I do not get why the SEA RSV requires me to disable soft delete temporarily.
